# If $A \subset \sigma(B)$ and sets in A are disjoint then $P(A) \subset \sigma(B)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, general-topology

A, B infinite if necessary.

If $A \subset \sigma(B)$ and sets in A are disjoint (Let me know if this is necessary) then $P(A) \subset \sigma(B)$?

($\sigma(\cdot)$ denotes sigma-algebra generated by.)

Can we simply say that every set in $P(A)$ can be expressed as a union of disjoint sets? It's intuitive but how to prove it?

Comment: This makes no sense as written. If $A\subseteq\sigma(B)$, and $C\in\wp(A)$, then $C\subseteq A\subseteq\sigma(B)$: members of $\wp(A)$ are **subsets** of $\sigma(B)$, not **elements** of $\sigma(B)$, as they would be if $\wp(A)$ were a subset of $\sigma(B)$. Are you really asking whether every union of members of $A$ is in $\sigma(B)$? That’s false in general: take $A$ to be $\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R\}$ and $\sigma(B)$ to be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R$, and note that $\sigma(B)\ne\wp(\Bbb R)$.